# How does electron app open another electron app?

Tags: javascript, windows, electron

A project has multiple applications. I thought of separating them instead of combining them in one application. How to open other applications when applications are separated. I tried it with deep link but when I was working on mac. This method does not work on Windows. Because when I do this on windows I get the warning "You'll need a new app to open this myapp". For example:

```
const {shell} = require('electron');
shell.openExternal('myapp://');
```

Comment: Are you sure your other app (the one you need to open) is associated correctly with the `myapp` protocol on Windows? It looks like it's not.

Comment: It is not actually associated. That's my goal anyway. I want to know that there is a non-application and redirect to my download address.